# Newsletter with a background image

Tags: css, html-table, html-email, newsletter

I want to create a newsletter with a background image/frame and I was wondering what is the best way to do that. If you have any suggestions please share.

The background image is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNm7c.png)

This is the code that I manage to write so far but I can't find a way to center the td and also I will have to add on top of the image text and logos. Would that be possible and if it is, would it be compatible with most of the email clients used like outlook or gmail?

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>

  <div style="background-color:#ffffff;">
    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
      <v:background xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="t">
        <v:fill type="tile" src="https://i.imgur.com/xRYqx1Y.png" color="#7bceeb"/>
      </v:background>
      <![endif]-->
    <table align='middle' height="100%" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" repeat="none">
      <tr>
        <td align='middle' valign="middle" style="background-repeat: no-repeat; text-align: center;" background="https://i.imgur.com/xRYqx1Y.png">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

> Like everything in email design and development, background images
>   have mixed support across email clients. Most clients support one 
>   techniques described below, the most notable exclusions being
>   earlier versions of Android, some Gmail clients, and some of the
>   webmail clients, which vary greatly depending on which browser is
>   used.

**The closer we can get is by using BULLETPROOF BACKGROUNDS**

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td background="https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNm7c.png" bgcolor="#7bceeb" valign="top">
      <!--[if gte mso 9]>
          <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="mso-width-percent:1000;">
            <v:fill type="tile" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNm7c.png" color="#7bceeb" />
            <v:textbox style="mso-fit-shape-to-text:true" inset="0,0,0,0">
          <![endif]-->
      <div>
        test
      </div>
      <!--[if gte mso 9]>
            </v:textbox>
          </v:rect>
          <![endif]-->
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But even in that, we have limitations in some major clients like ***Gmail Chrome*** for more details read this [**article**](https://litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-background-images-in-email) from *JASON RODRIGUEZ*.

Comment: +1 for this but you will need more than one background decleration for support. Use `background:url()` and `background-image:url()` in CSS for wider support.

Answer (score 0):

Add class to your table. Then in CSS file  use the code like this
.class{background-image:URL(/image.png) no-repeat;}

Comment: Not supported by outlook

Comment: Not supported by Android. - https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/color-background/background-image/